# Does Java define the size of its primitive types anywhere?

Tags: java, primitive, primitive-types

Is there a package that defines the size of Java primitives that I can import in my project? I'm doing some manual bit setting and I keep a byte index. I don't want to do `currentByte += 4` when I set an int (magic numbers are frowned upon), I rather do `currentByte += <SomePackage>.SIZE_OF_INT`

I guess I can define my own, but that's kind of clunky, especially if those are available somewhere.

Comment: [Primitive Datatypes in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: If you're using `currentByte`, then there's probably a better data structure you can use, such as a buffer.

Comment: I'm trying to keep changes to minimum due to process reasons, but will give that a thought.

Comment: Just noting that I would be *very* tempted to use a `byte[]` if you are dealing with fixed byte manipulations.  If you get more into bit level manipulations, you might find the BigInteger useful as it also has testBit and setBit methods (along with other bit level methods)... and then you don't care about its size.

Comment: That's what was used originally. I ended up using ByteBuffer instead - it's much cleaner and takes care of all the indexing.

Comment: The sizes of Java primitive are very precisely documented in the JVM spec and probably also in the language spec.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not a class, but you have `Integer.SIZE`, and so on for `Long` and floating point classes too. You also have `*.BYTES`.

Therefore `Integer.SIZE` is 32, `Integer.BYTES` is 4, `Double.SIZE` is 64 and `Double.BYTES` is 8, etc etc; all of these are `int`s in case you were wondering.

**NOTE: `*.BYTES` are only defined since Java 8 (thanks @Slanec for noticing)**

(`*.SIZE` appeared in Java 5 but you *do* use at least that, right?)

And yes, this is defined by the JDK since the JLS itself defines the size of primitive types; you are therefore guaranteed that you'll have the same values for these constants on whatever Java implementation on whatever platform.

Comment: Java SE 7 is my target distro.

Comment: @ventsyv then you have at least `*.SIZE`

Answer (score 9):

The specification for the size of primitives is contained in the Java Language Specification, [Section 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).

This is *the* standard and will not change, so one doesn't need to import them in. You can use them as magic numbers (though as [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29416910/289086) points out, that these are magic numbers that are stored in sensible places in the various wrapper classes since Java 5 and you should use those rather than redefining them yourself).

Comment: @shookees any change of these values would be a breaking change for all class files and their backwards and forwards compatibility. That 'your code no longer works *as intended*' would be a minor one compared to the 'your code no longer works'. I don't believe that these could change at all and remain Java. Given that `Integer.SIZE` is a static final and is replaced at compile time, using the value in Integer, if it were to change, would likewise be a breaking change for it to change in a later version.

Comment: @shookees while I absolutely do agree that standards change, I would be comfortable calling this the kind of thing that would generally not change.  Oracle is behind Java, and Oracle is not the kind of company to change such things.  Looking at standards by similar companies and consortiums, this is the kind of detail they would bend over backwards to avoid changing.  If the language spec got strained enough to cause Oracle to change this, I have a feeling there would be so many other issues that sizes would be the least of your worries.

Comment: Is there any way by which Java code could distinguish between an implementation where primitives had the indicated sizes from one where all primitives occupied 13 bytes of space, and arrays of any primitive type occupied 13 bytes per element?  One would expect memory to hold only an eighth as many `long[1000000]` instances as `byte[1000000]` instances, but since the number of such instances that will fit in memory isn't specified in either case, I don't think that would be an "observable" difference.

Comment: BTW, the problem with using magic numbers is not that they might change, but rather that they appear magic to those viewing them. A bushell might always be 9.6 US gallons, but that doesn't make it any easier when I read your code.